# How to auto mount drive with user permissions

Tags: mount, fstab, chown

When I mount a drive using fstab, it is owned by root, and I cannot write to it. I have tried chowning the folder where it gets mounted but it does nothing while mounted, and doing it when unmounted fixes, but when it mounts it gets set back to root.

Comment: "it is owned by root" No it is owned by the user you set in the fstab line for windows system (`rw,user,exec,mode=1777`)  1 thing we do need: what is the filesystem of that drive? windows based? or linux based?

Comment: @Rinzwind it is fat32 partition

Comment: windows mounts do not use linux rules so chmod/chown commands are invalid. You set the user using fstab with the bit in my previous comment ;)

Answer (score -1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Per-User_Mounts
Used udisksctl and startup applications to mount it, I am able to write to it now.